# Stop Segue and show alert partially not working - Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, alert

I earlier had an issue with stopping the segue and showing an alert if the textFields were empty. That problem is solved. I now want to further run the content of these textfields through a few logical tests. However, my code doesn't seem to be catching the errors. Code as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Darwin

class View3on3 : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}


func initializeTextFields()
{
    APTeams.delegate = self
    APTeams.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APRounds.delegate = self
    APRounds.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APBreakers.delegate = self
    APBreakers.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty || APRounds.text!.isEmpty || APBreakers.text!.isEmpty)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Data missing!",
                message: "Please enter valid data into all 3 fields.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) < Int(String(APBreakers.text)))
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Math Error!",
                message: "The number of breaking teams cannot be more than the number of teams.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) > 9999)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Math Error!",
                message: "Please input a number of teams less than 10,000.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else
        {
            let DestViewController : View3on3Results = segue.destinationViewController as! View3on3Results

            DestViewController.AP1 = APTeams.text!
            DestViewController.AP2 = APRounds.text!
            DestViewController.AP3 = APBreakers.text!

            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueTest",sender: View3on3Results.self)//
        }



        }

}
```

Anyone know what's up? The first test for non-empty fields is working fine and throws an error if any of the 3 textFields are empty.

Also, if anyone knows how to test to make sure the entries contain integers only, that'd be much appreciated. That's the second test I need to run before testing for the value of the integers.

Addendum: I'm using XCode 7 beta 4, writing in Swift 2.0.

Edit: My code now looks like this, and now the segue just happens without checking at all.

@derdida Tried to follow what you said. The segue just happened without checking any of the conditions. Could you correct my updated code?

```
func checkIfPassed() {

    if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty || APRounds.text!.isEmpty || APBreakers.text!.isEmpty)
    {
        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Data missing!",
            message: "Please enter valid data into all 3 fields.",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) < Int(String(APBreakers.text)))
    {
        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Math Error!",
            message: "The number of breaking teams cannot be more than the number of teams.",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) > 9999)
    {
        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Math Error!",
            message: "Please input a number of teams less than 10,000.",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else
    {
        // everything is fine, so manually go to your next ViewController
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("3on3Segue", sender: nil)
    }


   }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       let DestViewController : View3on3Results = segue.destinationViewController as! View3on3Results

            DestViewController.AP1 = APTeams.text!
            DestViewController.AP2 = APRounds.text!
            DestViewController.AP3 = APBreakers.text!
        }
```

Comment: change this lines: `else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) < Int(String(APBreakers.text)))` with `else if APTeams.text.toInt() < APBreakers.text.toInt() ` and `else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) > 9999)` with `else if APTeams.text.toInt() > 9999`

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7 beta 4, in Swift 2. The toInt initializer has been removed @DharmeshKheni :/

Comment: ok I didn't know that because I am using 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your code a little bit.

Connect your ViewController1 to your ViewController2 (not the Button), so you are able to manually perform a segue. I would not go into "prepareForSegue" - i would write my own "check if passed" function, like that:

```
    func checkIfPassed() {

        if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty || APRounds.text!.isEmpty || APBreakers.text!.isEmpty)
        {
           // show your first alert
        } else if(APTeams.text.toInt() != nil && ABreakers.text.toInt() != nil)) {
           // ok, both values are no integers, show your next error

           // show your second alert

        } else if(APTeams.text.toInt() < ABreakers.text.toInt()) { 
           // values are integers, and ABreakers.text is > then APTeams.text
           // show your third alert, and so on

        } else {
           // everything is fine, so manually go to your next ViewController
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", nil)
        }


    }
```

Update: You can now check your Strings if they are integers with Optionals: (Swift 2.0)

```
 let text:Int? = Int(textfield.text)
```

Comment: I'm new to coding in Swift, I understand the logical tests, but absolutely don't get how to Segue is called. If you look at my code for the Segue, I also use the segue to pass data to the next View Controller. Could you write out the code that shows me how this is done in full?

Really apologize and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can still use "prepareForSegue" - with performSegueWithIdentifier its the same like you connect an UIButton with an ViewController, and press this button. Youre just doing that manually.

Comment: If your write that code "outside" your "prepareForSegue" function its much cleaner - you can "reuse" your code maybe for another controller. And you just go into segues when all values are validated.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that. Much cleaner. Two quick questions:

1) Why didn't this code work?
2) How do I know what my SegueIdentifier is?

Comment: Which error? Click on your Segue (in your Storyboard) - on the right side you are able to write an identifier: Or check here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3w9Lj.png

Comment: See the latest edit to my question. I've tried to implement your code, but it isn't working (probably my fault for missing something)

Comment: Probably you have still a connection from your UIButton? to the nextViewController OR everything passed (so the script goes to the last "else" section) check out and use "println("test1")" 2,3,4 in different parts of your code, to check what your app does.

Comment: None of the tests should have been passed. It's probably a connection from UIButton. How do I get check for that and get rid of it? In that case, will the segue still happen upon Button press?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84049/discussion-between-thevesh-theva-and-derdida).

Answer (score 0):

Prepare for segue will let you configure your data as needed and will fire perform segue. What you should do: get action that will trigger this segue: Tap gesture, button action or anything else. There, you do the validation and if everything is ok, do

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueTest",sender: View3on3Results.self)
```