# Why isn't this If argument being implemented?

Tags: ios

I asked a question about this earlier ([Stop Segue and show alert partially not working - Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580960/stop-segue-and-show-alert-partially-not-working-xcode/31581239?noredirect=1#comment51117006_31581239))

and received answers that asked me to implement different methods of checking the textfield before segue. However, I realised that something was amiss because one of my IF arguments was being run perfectly fine.

This is the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Darwin

class View3on3 : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}


func initializeTextFields()
{
    APTeams.delegate = self
    APTeams.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APRounds.delegate = self
    APRounds.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APBreakers.delegate = self
    APBreakers.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty || APRounds.text!.isEmpty || APBreakers.text!.isEmpty)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Data missing!",
                message: "Please enter valid data into all 3 fields.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) < Int(String(APBreakers.text)))
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Math Error!",
                message: "The number of breaking teams cannot be more than the number of teams.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) > 9999)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Math Error!",
                message: "The number of breaking teams cannot be more than the number of teams.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else
        {
            let DestViewController : View3on3Results = segue.destinationViewController as! View3on3Results

            DestViewController.AP1 = APTeams.text!
            DestViewController.AP2 = APRounds.text!
            DestViewController.AP3 = APBreakers.text!

        } 
        }
}
```

It's running the textfield input through the first IF function perfectly fine. Screenshots here:

[image][image]

but when I key this in (which should fulfil the first ELSE IF function and show an alert:

[image]

It just segues as normal.

Why is this happening? Help much appreciated. =)

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: I would suggest that you split out the conversion to Int into separate statements (putting the values into local variables) and set a breakpoint so that you can examine the variables and see what is happening.

Comment: My guess would be the text fields have not been commited into the IBOutlets, so the `else if` is not `else if (50 < 51)` but something else. Print out the values of the two text variables. If this `else if` is missed, then unless teams is > 9999 it will segue which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't do this sort of checking in this method, you should implement `shouldPerformSegue` - if you return false from this method then he segue is aborted.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 and @ RoryMcKinnel . Am going to debug and see if I can sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (Int(String(APTeams.text)) < Int(String(APBreakers.text)))
```

This is not executing because its not true. Split this up, convert the strings into ints first before this check and then compare then ints directly in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (Int(APTeams.text!) > Int(APBreakers.text!))
```

Check please I have edited my answer

Comment: this doesn't work in Swift 2. They got rid of this method.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't knew that. Did you try just Int without String?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @RoryMcKinnel and @Paulw11 for the advice on debugging and checking the variables. Once I did that, I was able to find the problem. It was simply a matter of where I initialised the variables and when they got mutated.

Fixed code here:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Darwin

class View3on3 : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}


func initializeTextFields()
{
    APTeams.delegate = self
    APTeams.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APRounds.delegate = self
    APRounds.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APBreakers.delegate = self
    APBreakers.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var team:Int = 0
        var round:Int = 0
        var breaky:Int = 0

        if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty || APRounds.text!.isEmpty || APBreakers.text!.isEmpty)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Data missing!",
                message: "Please enter valid data into all 3 fields.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        else
        {
            var teams:String = String(APTeams.text!)
            var rounds:String = String(APRounds.text!)
            var breakers:String = String(APBreakers.text!)

            team = Int(teams)!
            round = Int(rounds)!
            breaky = Int(breakers)!
        }

        if ( breaky > team)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Math Error!",
                message: "The number of breaking teams cannot be more than the number of teams.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if (team > 9999)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Too Many Teams!",
                message: "Please input a number of teams less than 10,000.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if (round < 0 || round > 9)
        {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Too Many Rounds!",
                message: "Please input a number of rounds between 1 and 9.",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else
        {
            let DestViewController : View3on3Results = segue.destinationViewController as! View3on3Results

            DestViewController.AP1 = APTeams.text!
            DestViewController.AP2 = APRounds.text!
            DestViewController.AP3 = APBreakers.text!

        }



        }


}
```

Comment: @Tander this was my solution